# Как отобразить данные из строки таблицы в модальном окне, которое вызвано из этой строки?

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap

Верстка на Bootstrap. Есть модальное окно, оно вызывается путем двойного клика на строку таблицы. Нужно чтобы данные из строки из которой вызвано модальное окно отображались в этом модальном окне.
Вызов модального окна выглядит на данный момент выглядит так:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".usrtbl").dblclick(function(){
        $("#idModalEditUser").modal('show');
    });
});
</script>
```

Сейчас при нажатии на любую строку таблицы выводится модальное окно с пустой формой.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".usrtbl").dblclick(function() {
    $("#idModalEditUser").modal('show');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />


<div>
  <table>
    <tr class="usrtbl" id="1">
      <td>11</td>
      <td>12</td>
      <td>13</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="usrtbl" id="2">
      <td>21</td>
      <td>22</td>
      <td>23</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="usrtbl" id="3">
      <td>31</td>
      <td>32</td>
      <td>33</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>

<!--Модальное окно-->

<div class="modal fade" id="idModalEditUser" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: разметку покажите, а лучше сделайте в сниппете воспроизводимый пример

Comment: берите `closest('tr')`, извлекайте данные из ячеек, и прописывайте в контролы модалки, либо если клик по строке, то не надо `closest`

Comment: @humster_spb добавил сниппет

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPD**
Тогда получаете по отдельности значения ячеек в строке и в каждый инпут заносите это значение:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".usrtbl").dblclick(function(){
    let one = $(this).children('td:first-child').text();
    let two = $(this).children('td:nth-child(2)').text();
    let three = $(this).children('td:last-child').text();
    $('#one').val(one);
    $('#two').val(two);
    $('#three').val(three);
    $("#idModalEditUser").modal('show');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />


<div>
  <table>
    <tr class="usrtbl" id="1">
      <td>11</td>
      <td>12</td>
      <td>13</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="usrtbl" id="2">
      <td>21</td>
      <td>22</td>
      <td>23</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="usrtbl" id="3">
      <td>31</td>
      <td>32</td>
      <td>33</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>

<!--Модальное окно-->

<div class="modal fade" id="idModalEditUser" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <form>
          <div class="form-row">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="one">Один</label>
              <input type="text" name="one" class="form-control" id="one">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="two">Два</label>
              <input type="text" name="two" class="form-control" id="two">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="three">Три</label>
              <input type="text" name="three" class="form-control" id="three">
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

Просто передавайте в модальное окно $(this).text()

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".usrtbl").dblclick(function() {
    $("#idModalEditUser").modal('show');
    $("#idModalEditUser .modal-body").text($(this).text());
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />


<div>
  <table>
    <tr class="usrtbl" id="1">
      <td>11</td>
      <td>12</td>
      <td>13</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="usrtbl" id="2">
      <td>21</td>
      <td>22</td>
      <td>23</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="usrtbl" id="3">
      <td>31</td>
      <td>32</td>
      <td>33</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>

<!--Модальное окно-->

<div class="modal fade" id="idModalEditUser" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: А если вот так? Просто у меня в модальном окне находится форма и она должна заполниться соответствующими данными из ячеек строки таблицы.
Грубо говоря, из первой ячейки в input - Один, из второй в input - Два и т.д. https://jsfiddle.net/myzu3kh7/2/

Comment: @DamirFelix, я обновил ответ

Comment: А что означают td:first-child и т.д.? Если у меня например больше ячеек, чем 3.

Comment: @DamirFelix, это селекторы дочерних элементов - чтобы не присваивать каждому какой-то свой класс или id, можно обращаться td:nth-child(1), td:nth-child(2) и т.д. в зависимости от того, сколько у Вас ячеек

Answer (score 1):

Надеюсь все понятно расписал, если у вас динамическая таблица пользуйтесь циклами, так же можно и модальное окно изменять на основе количества данных.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(".usrtbl").dblclick(function() {
    clear_modal(); //Очистка можно так же циклом, принцип показал ниже
    var col_arr = []; //Иницализация масива
    var rowData = $(this).children(); //Получаем кучу <td> из тега <tr>
    
    for(var i = 0; i < $(this).children().length;i++){
      //Засовываем значения в масив для более удобной работы с ними
      col_arr.push($(rowData[i]).text()); 
    }
    
    console.log(col_arr); //Выводит значения стобцов
    
    for(var i = 0; i <= col_arr.length; i++){
      //Вместо имени можешь использовать data тэг и радоваться жизни
      $('input[name=col_'+(Number(i)+1)+']').val(col_arr[i]);
    }
    
    /* // Или так если не динамическая таблица
    $('input[name=col_1]').val(col_arr[0]);
    $('input[name=col_2]').val(col_arr[1]);
    $('input[name=col_3]').val(col_arr[2]);
    */
    $("#idModalEditUser").modal('show');
  });
  
  
  function clear_modal() { // Очистка модального окна
    $('input[name=col_1]').val("");
    $('input[name=col_2]').val("");
    $('input[name=col_3]').val("");
  }
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />


<div>
  <table id="MyTable">
    <tr class="usrtbl" id="1">
      <td>11</td>
      <td>12</td>
      <td>13</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="usrtbl" id="2">
      <td>21</td>
      <td>22</td>
      <td>23</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="usrtbl" id="3">
      <td>31</td>
      <td>32</td>
      <td>33</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>

<!--Модальное окно-->

<div class="modal fade" id="idModalEditUser" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="form-group row">
            <label for="" class="col-form-label col-sm-3 col-form-label-sm">Значение 1:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-9">
              <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" name="col_1">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group row">
            <label for="" class="col-form-label col-sm-3 col-form-label-sm">Значение 2:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-9">
              <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" name="col_2">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group row">
            <label for="" class="col-form-label col-sm-3 col-form-label-sm">Значение 3:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-9">
              <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" name="col_3">
            </div>
          </div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Сохранить</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: А как заполнить таблицу в модальном окне, т.е. если вместо инпутов, тег td?

Comment: @DamirFelix так же, заместо `$('input[name=col_1]').val("");`  пишешь `$('td[name=col_1]').val("");` или что-то такое, смотря по какому тэгу хочешь

Answer (score 0):

Данные из строки отображаются в модальном окне по двойному клику:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  const $modal = $("#idModalEditUser");
  const $modalBody = $modal.find('.modal-body');
  $(".usrtbl").dblclick(function(e) {
    $modalBody.text(null);
    [...this.children].map((item, index)=> {
      $modalBody.append(` (${index} элемент: ${item.innerText})`);
    });
    $modal.modal('show');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />


<div>
  <table>
    <tr class="usrtbl" id="1">
      <td>11</td>
      <td>12</td>
      <td>13</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="usrtbl" id="2">
      <td>21</td>
      <td>22</td>
      <td>23</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="usrtbl" id="3">
      <td>31</td>
      <td>32</td>
      <td>33</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>

<!--Модальное окно-->

<div class="modal fade" id="idModalEditUser" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```